Groovy / Jenkins - Could not find matching constructor on Override
I have a question/problem here that I can’t resolve.
I created a code in Groovy that aims to execute a command (shell) in a Docker container that is already running. And I use the com.github.dockerjava libraries (If there is something simpler, I would appreciate it.
The code has worked perfectly in GroovyConsole or IntelliJ.
The error only occurs when I have this code in Shared Library and run the pipe in Jenkins
Groovy 4.0.14
java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --version
2.440.1
The complete code is at: https://github.com/faustobranco/jenkinscommunity/tree/master/ExecDocker 1
The error occurs in the Override of ResultCallback.Adapter in this code snippet:
        def obj_Return = obj_dockerClient
                .execStartCmd(obj_cmd_exec)
                .withTty(true)
                .exec(new ResultCallback.Adapter<Frame>() {
                    @Override
                    void onNext(Frame object) {
                        def str_tmp_result = new String(object.getPayload()).trim();
                        obj_Log.info(str_tmp_result)
                        std_out.append(str_tmp_result);
                        super.onNext(object);
                    }
                    @Override
                    void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        def str_tmp_result = new String(throwable as String).trim();
                        std_err.append(str_tmp_result);
                        super.onError(throwable);
                    }
                    @Override
                    void onComplete() {
                        std_complete=true;
                        super.onComplete();
                    }
                })

Error:
23:03:35   [INFO] [ExecDocker] Can't exec Docker commandgroovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: devopsdb.docker.ExecDocker$1(devopsdb.docker.ExecDocker, devopsdb.log.Logger, java.lang.StringBuilder) - Line: [groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1742), groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1549), org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:48), org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59), org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:238), com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.constructorCall(DefaultInvoker.java:25), org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.LoggingInvoker.constructorCall(LoggingInvoker.java:110), devopsdb.docker.ExecDocker.run_Command(ExecDocker.groovy:69), WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:38), ___cps.transform___(Native Method), com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:100), com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85), jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor223.invoke(Unknown Source), java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source), java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source), com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72), com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39), com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30), com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28), com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55), com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16), com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83), com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:147), org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:17), org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:49), org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:180), org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:423), org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:331), org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:295), org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$wrap$4(CpsVmExecutorService.java:136), java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source), hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139), jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28), jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68), jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51), java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source), java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source), java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source), java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source), org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:53), org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50), org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136), org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275), org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$categoryThreadFactory$0(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50), java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)]

